# issue with eigs_sym for obtaining eigenvalues with smallest magnitude

Tags: c++, qt, armadillo

i'm trying to get a limited number of eigen-values with smallest magnitude of a squared symmetric matrix. 
To do this, i'm using first the example in the doc of Armadillo (http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eigs_sym) :

```
sp_mat A = sprandu<sp_mat>(1000, 1000, 0.1);
sp_mat B = A.t()*A;
arma::vec eigval;
mat eigvec;
eigs_sym(eigval, eigvec, B, 10, "sm");//i add "sm" to get the eigen-  
                                      //values of smallest magnitude
cout<<eigval<<endl;
```

Here i obtain an error saying the ddcomposition fails [failed to converge].

However, when i called eigs_sym like this:

```
eigs_sym(eigval, eigvec, B, 10); //obtain the eigen-values with 
                                 //LARGEST magnitude (default call)
```

this work well and i get the expected result:

```
1.1596e+02
1.1680e+02
1.1785e+02
1.1815e+02
1.1927e+02
1.2017e+02
1.2108e+02
1.2256e+02
1.2323e+02
2.5413e+03
```

i'm on Ubuntu Os, and here is my .pro file (Qt) :

```
 LIBS += -lgsl -lgslcblas -lX11 -lpthread -llapack  -lm -fopenmp   
         -larmadillo
```

Any idea for resolving this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issure by choosing a higher number of eigenvalues to extract. 
Apparently, a lower number of eigenvalues to extract makes the eigensolver to note converge. If you replace

```
eigs_sym(eigval, eigvec, B, 10,"sm")
```

by

```
eigs_sym(eigval, eigvec, B, 100,"sm")
```

this will work.

Comment: This is strange and should not be the case. The underlying algorithm that armadillo uses (calling the ARPACK library) is the [arnoldi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration). It is designed for finding a _small_ number of eigenvalues _at the edge_ of the eigenspectrum of the operator or matrix in question.

Comment: zero eigenvalues are usually targeted via a so called [shift-and-invert routine](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/UG/node33.html), for which you are usually also required to supply the program with the action of the inverse of the matrix or operator. However I think I remember that arpack somehow manages to do without. Any way it should actually work _better_ when you target fewer eigenvalues.

Comment: Can you give the exact error message you receive and also an example of the matrix/operator you are studying? This whole thing smells like a known  [compatibility bug](https://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/arpack-ng/issues/1315/) in the arpack library...

Comment: the error when i call the   eigs_sym(eigval, eigvec, A , 5,"sm");  is : 
error: eigs_sym(): failed to converge
If i put "15" instead of  "5", this will work. 
A is a Sparse Laplacian Matrix constructed from a 3D mesh